Return CELL REFERENCE from a multiple criteria Filter function
Here is my current formula:
=FILTER(Followup!G:G,(Followup!E:E=A152)*(Followup!AA:AA=$N$1))

As you can see, this is filtering a range based on two criteria. Essentially it is searching the E and AA columns and returning the G column. This is successful in returning the contents of the intended cell from the G column. However, I am trying to return the cell reference, not the contents.
I have wrapped this in the CELL() function to no success. I have also found many other ways, using XLOOKUP() for instance, returning the contents but not the reference, and they resist being wrapped in CELL() as well. I would prefer to keep the filter function. Any ideas?

Is this resolved now or is it still pending? I don't see any response.

If understood correctly, then this is what you may trying to achieve, and here is what you can do, shown with some example data, you may need to change the cell reference and ranges as per your suit:


=FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(G:G),7),(I2=A:A)*(J2=E:E),"Oops Not Found")


So, in context of your post it would be like, need to use ADDRESS() function:
=FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(Followup!G:G),7),(Followup!E:E=A152)*(Followup!AA:AA=$N$1),"Not Found"))


Also, it is not needed and will be unnecessary to call CELL() function, won't work in that way, to make it work, you can take help of LAMBDA() helper function called MAP() but it is not required, as ADDRESS() function does the job,
=FILTER(MAP(G:G,LAMBDA(x,CELL("address",x))),(A:A=I2)*(J2=E:E),"")




